# Determine CAS user automatically on public (permitAll()) page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-cas

I am using Spring Security with Spring Boot and authenticate my users via JASIG CAS. Some of the pages require explicitly authentication (.authenticated()) and some of them are for all users.

Now there is a certain area in the menu, which indicates the current user and possible actions, like login/logout.

My main problem is now that the main page is public (permitAll()) and that, if a user already has a CAS session through some other application, he is shown as "anonymousUser" until login is clicked manually or a protected page is opened.

Is there somebody who has any ideas on how to get this working?

My security configuration:

```
import org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties;
import org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider;
 import org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.AuthenticationUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Autowired
private CasAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Bean
public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
    ServiceProperties sp = new ServiceProperties();
    sp.setSendRenew(false);
    sp.setService(env.getProperty("app.url") + "/j_spring_cas_security_check");
    return sp;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Autowired
private AuthenticationUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
    return new CASUserDetailsService();
}


@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
    CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas20ServiceTicketValidator());
    casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only");
    return casAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public Cas20ServiceTicketValidator cas20ServiceTicketValidator() {
    return new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(env.getProperty("cas.service.url"));
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    return casAuthenticationFilter;
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    CasAuthenticationEntryPoint ep = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    ep.setLoginUrl(env.getProperty("cas.service.url") + "/login");
    ep.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    return ep;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**").antMatchers("/fonts/**").antMatchers("/images/**").antMatchers("/css/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling().
            authenticationEntryPoint(casAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and().addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter()).
            logout().logoutUrl("/caslogout").addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler()).logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and().
            csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll().
            antMatchers("/login/**").authenticated().antMatchers("/settings/**").authenticated().
            antMatchers("/projects/*/settings").authenticated().antMatchers("/projects/*/role").authenticated().
            antMatchers("/projects/*/*/admin").authenticated().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
}


@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    CASAuthSuccessHandler auth = new CASAuthSuccessHandler();
    return auth;
}

@Bean
public CASLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
    CASLogoutHandler logout = new CASLogoutHandler();
    return logout;
}


@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is CAS's Gateway feature. Currently this is not supported in Spring Security. There is a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-977) logged to support it and a [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/40) that is waiting additional modifications based on my feedback to the submitter.

I'd take a look at the Pull Request as it demonstrates a few options on how to implement this. Please do read through the whole thing as you will need to make some changes to the Pull Request to ensure your application performs.